# O que é EntityFramework e como usa-lo com C# e conexão com bancos de dados PostgreeSql e MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Estou programando um CRUD de alunos em ADO com C# e MySql, meu professor de algoritmos me disse sobre o Entity, mas não consigo encontrar algo claro que faça a conexão entre os bancos. Alguém me explica?

Comment: que faça a conexão entre os bancos? quanto bancos você esta usando?

Comment: o Entity vai criar uma camada para abstrair detalhes do banco de dados, imagina que o C# não precisa saber qual banco vc está usando, ele vai falar com Entity, que por sua vez vai fazer todo o tramite com o banco de dados. Segue um link para você estudar a respeito: http://www.macoratti.net/09/06/vb_iaef.htm

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto Obrigado, simples e claro, vou estudar !

Comment: Só seguir. http://imasters.com.br/artigo/13681/mysql/conectando-c-ao-mysql?trace=1519021197&source=single